# Haarcascade operates on 348x288 images only?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, haar-classifier

I am using opencv and c++. Which face detector algorithm to use if I have 348x288 face images. In the paper for Haarcascade http://www.vision.caltech.edu/html-files/EE148-2005-Spring/pprs/viola04ijcv.pdf, it is said that haarcascade operates on 348x288 pixel images. Does that mean I cannot use haarcascade to detect the faces in my images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be used for your images as long as you setup the correct parameters for [`CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale), especially the following three:

- **scaleFactor** – Parameter specifying how much the image size is reduced at each image scale.
- **minSize** – Minimum possible object size. Objects smaller than that are ignored.
- **maxSize** – Maximum possible object size. Objects bigger than that are ignored.

Comment: Yes it does detect but I still have some doubts regarding haarcascade_profileface. When I used it with a profile image,it does not detect anything. I also used lbpcascade_profileface but no results. I want to be able to detect the profile face area and the ears as well in one picture. I tried increasing the width of the rectangle but it does not work

Comment: @Steph It happens sometimes. The faces cascades are not perfect as it is trained on images (or features) that may not look similar to yours.

Comment: okay!Are there any other face detection methods for profile images available in opencv?

Comment: @Steph The answer is NO unfortunately.